# JavaFX how to get control characters from TextField

Tags: javafx

Currently I have a simple JavaFX application with the following TextField

```
<TextField id="textfield-EmvTagData" fx:id="textfield_EmvTagData" alignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="4" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
```

The user (me in this case) gets a string of data which contains non printable characters (0x1C specifically).

When I later try and execute the following code I get all the text back however the control characters (0x1C) have been removed.  My application needs these control characters in order to parse the data.  With my old JSwing application JTextField had no problem handling this but I am out of ideas with JavaFX.

Any ideas on how to get all the text in the JavaFX TextField including the control characters that were copied and pasted into it?

Comment: Define *"getting a String of data"*. Where does that string come from?

Comment: @fabian the string of text which contains the control character (0x1C) comes from an application that I have no control over.  I then want to copy and paste that data into the TextField (code in my original question).  The goal is to get that string as is by calling textfield-EmvTagData.getText with the control characters still there.  It appears that the JavaFX TextField is stripping the control characters (0x1C) so I am looking for help on how to maintain the integrity of that data in the TextField.